# What does the notation $D = \mathrm{diag}(W\cdot1)$ mean?

Tags: matrices, notation

What does the notation $D = \mathrm{diag}(W\cdot1)$ mean in the following excerpt from [this paper](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Aging_KDD2015_camera-ready.pdf)?

[image]

Comment: The answers given below are right. I just want to point out that that paper provides a good example of what *not* to do when expressing ideas mathematically—failing to define notations before using them (what's $m_i$)?), using different font variants in a way that obscures the underlying type ($\mathbf{W}_{ij}$ and $\mathbf{x}(t)$ are actually scalars), and failing to change human-readable words from italic to roman in equations ("diag", "seg", "otherwise").

Comment: X-posted: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/33037/20417

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_K)^\top\in\Bbb C^K$, one often writes

$$\mathrm{diag}(v)=\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
0 & v_2 & \ddots  & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots& 0 \\
0 &  \dots & 0  & v_K
\end{pmatrix} \in\Bbb C^{K\times K}.$$

Here,

$$ v=W\cdot  \mathbf{1},$$

where $\mathbf{1}$ means the vector $(1,\ldots,1)^\top\in\Bbb C^K$, so

$$ v_i = \sum_{j=1}^K W_{ij}\cdot 1, \quad i=1,\ldots,K.$$

Comment: Ewww, writing $1$ to mean a vector is so gross . . . surely there’s something better

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor $$\sum_{j=1}^{n} e_j?$$ :P

Comment: @XanderHenderson Ahhhhh much better. Maybe call it . . . $E$. It’s not your fault though!

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor $E$ could work.  It might cause some ambiguity with, for example, a *matrix* containing only $1$s... maybe $E_{m\times 1}$ if we are worried about such an ambiguity (drop the subscript if not)?

Comment: @XanderHenderson What a headache

Comment: Note that $E$ and $e_k$ are already used in the paper with a different meaning. `$\mathbf{1}$` $\mathbf{1}$ works too.

Answer (score 4):

$L$ is a sort of Laplacian matrix, defined by subtracting the original matrix $W$ from the matrix whose diagonal contains its row sums. In other words, $D$ is the diagonal matrix with $D_{ij}=0$ when $i\neq j$ and $D_{ii}=\sum_j W_{ij}$.

The notation "$\operatorname{diag}(v)$" means to make a matrix whose diagonal is the vector $v$, with zeros off the diagonal.

Here, $W\cdot 1$ means the multiplication of $W$ with the vector of ones, which turns out to compute the row sums: $[W1]_i=\sum_j W_{ij}1_j=\sum_{j}W_{ij}$.

Comment: It might be worth noting that (in contrast to your answer) the $1$ in the paper *is* bolded.

Comment: Totally. Don't know what I was looking at...